# ViewController nextButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance on swift 3

Tags: xcode, uibutton, swift3

The following function creates a button, and when I press on the button, `nextButtonPressed` is called but I keep getting error.

> unrecognized selector sent to instance.

```
 func createButton () {

    button.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)

    button.addTarget(self, action:Selector(("nextButtonPressed:")), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    button.isHidden = true
}
```

This is the `nextButtonPressed` which is being called.

```
func nextButtonPressed(sender:UIButton!) {
        print("next button was pressed")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `#selector` syntax to take advantage of checking the signature of the method at compile time.

```
... action: #selector(nextButtonPressed(_:)), ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add Selector in Swift 3**

```
#selector(methodName(_:))
```

Like this and we are **passing Parametter** then We use **"(_:)"** and have **no parametter** then **"()"**

In your Code Change Set selector like this

```
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(nextButtonPressed(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

Comment: There is no significant difference to my answer.